# Create this background effect using SVG / CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

My aim is to achieve a background like this. In easy words, I want to overlay / mask the white background svg over the plants' image. But as you see that the top of white background has an effect like when you tear a paper, is it possible to create such an effect using SVG or CSS?

[image: Sample Aim]

Comment: That's not a pattern.

Comment: @Dai sorry for the word. Can you give me any idea to achieve this? Specially with css?

Comment: I would use two images here: 1) a rectangular `.jpg` of the plant and 2) a plain white `.png`, the same size as the `.jpg`, with three straight sides and a jagged pseudo-top-edge (above which is only alpha transparency). Then use CSS `background-image` with multiple values, so that 2) sits above (and partially obscures) 1).

Comment: If you convert your image to png format, you can erase part of its contents and make that part transparent..